# Windows command line: How to sort files listed by where command?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a directory "shift" which contains a file named `YYYYMMDD_XXXXXX.xls` (e.g. `20180516_RP18VS.xls`) and lots of other files. I created a batch file to pick the desired file and open in Excel as read-only:

```
cd T:\shift
where 2018* > name.txt
set /p FILE=<name.txt
start excel /r %FILE%
del name.txt
```

Now the directory contains more XLS files named using the given scheme. How can I pick the most recent one (based on the filename, not the date of last edit)? I know I can order the files listed by dir command but what about where command?

Comment: Change `where 2018* > name.txt` to `where ".:2018*.xls" | sort /R > "name.txt"`, so you search in the current directory only (`.:`), you do not have files other than `*.xls` returned and you have the most recent file on top.

Comment: You realize that the `WHERE` command also searches for the file in all the folders listed in the `PATH` variable. You may want to limit the search by using the `/R` switch or use the `DIR` command.

Comment: @Squashman, I was about to suggest that as well, but `/R` would search also in sub-directories, and `dir [/B]` does not return full paths (unless you add `/S`, which I again wanted to avoid). `where` with the `.:` prefix limits the search to the current directory...

Comment: @aschipfl, yes.  So I am confused on why the user is using `WHERE` if they know what directory it is in.

Comment: @Squashman, I believe the Excel call needs an absolute path to the `*.xls` files as it may use a differrent (default) working directory, and `where` delivers them immediately; alternatively `dir /B` could be used when prepending the output with `%CD%`...